# How to show QListWidgetItems in a grid without eliding the text?

Tags: qt, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

I have a QListWidget. I set a grid size for QListWidget, to show items inside the list widget as a grid. But when font size of the dialog is increased, items that have long text are shown with an elide. How to remove this elide and show the full content of the items?

```cpp
QListWidget *listWidget = new QListWidget;

listWidget->setFlow(QListView::LeftToRight);

listWidget->setResizeMode(QListView::Adjust);

listWidget->setGridSize(QSize(100, 50));

listWidget->setSpacing(someInt);

listWidget->setViewMode(QListView::IconMode);
```

Comment: The width of the items is taken from the gridSize, in your case 100, so if the text has a larger width the text will be trimmed, so my question is: Do you want the width of the item to increase?

Comment: Contents of QListWidgetItems are generated dynamically in my case. So they can have any width. When I remove setting grid size, texts of the items that have long texts are not trimmed. But items are not vertically aligned. I want them to be aligned like in a grid.

Comment: That is why it is my doubt, if you want me to show all the text the width should increase, then from what I understand you want the width of each item to be the maximum width of all the texts. Am I correct?

Comment: Iterating over all the texts and find the maximum width of the text. Then setting that as the width of each item could work. Isn't there any other way? Like using a QStyledItemDelegate.

Comment: That same logic can be done in the delegate, but the basis of the solution is that: iterate and get the maximum width of all the texts to establish it in all the items.

Comment: The problem is, when the font size of the dialog is changed, that maximum width will be changed again. Then I will have to handle that event as well. When the font size is changed I will have to calculate the maximum length again and set that as the width of each item.